# get substring between two indexes using indexOf()

Tags: javascript, indexof

```
var myStr = "I love chocolate and strawberry, love this and that as well, and again love walking along the street";

var newStr = myStr.substr(myStr.indexOf('love'), myStr.lastIndexOf('love'));

///" chocolate and strawberry, "; //this is the output
```

```js
 var myStr = "I love chocolate and strawberry, love this and that as well, and again love walking along the street";
    
    var newStr = myStr.substr(myStr.indexOf('love'), myStr.lastIndexOf('love'));

console.log(newStr);
```

How do I get the text between the the first word 'love' and the second word "love" which should be " chocolate and strawberry, "?

Comment: `String.indexOf()` supports second param, `fromIndex` [(doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). If you store the result of the first `indexOf`, just reuse it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method with fromIndex argument.

```js
var myStr = "I love chocolate and strawberry, love this and that as well, and again love walking along the street";
var str='love', ind = myStr.indexOf(str);
var newStr = myStr.substring(ind + str.length , myStr.indexOf(str,ind + 1));

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your string with `love` :) and look at the second item in array:

```
var newStr = myStr.split("love")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with above answer, but if you want to know how to get the index of second "Love", you can pass the "startingPostion" in indexOf(), so it will look for word "Love" after the starting Position.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing is caused because the second index you're sending to the substring method is the beginning of the last word 'love'  and not the end of it... If you'll add the length of the word 'love'  to the second index,  your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap split into a function for easy use.

Just call `getTextBetween(splitOnString, middleTextDesired)` on your string.

`splitOnString` is the text you want to look between.

`middleTextDesired` is the number of middle text you want. `1` for 1st, `2` for 2nd, etc...

It's not a finished function as defensive checks are not added, but the idea is clear.

```js
var myStr = "I love chocolate and strawberry, love this and that as well, and again love walking along the street";
    
String.prototype.getTextBetween = function(splitOn, middleTextDesired = 1) {
  return this.split(splitOn)[middleTextDesired];
}

console.log(myStr.getTextBetween('love', 1));
```